# plotting multiple graphs on same axis with same color but different color intensities

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot multiple graphs on the same axis with the same color but different color intensities.
However, my results appear to have the same intensity for all colors, not sure how to fix this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iterations = 3
for i in range(iterations):
    data = np.random.normal(size=10)
    plt.plot(data, c="red",alpha=1/3)
plt.show()
```

[all 3 plots are having the same color intensity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ObTe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specified "red" for all rows. Your computer doesn't know that you expect a different red each time.

As you already tried, you can adjust the alpha value; however you need to set a different value at each iteration. You can do that by using the `i` loop variable.

For finer color control, use RGB "tuple" instead of a color name. That is, a tuple of three floats between 0.0 and 1.0, specifying the "red", "green" and "blue" component.

The standard "red" is `(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.

To get lighter shades, add some green and blue by increasing the `0.0` 's. To get darker shades, decrease the `1.0`.

Code::

```
for i in range(iterations):
    data = ...
    plt.plot(data, c=(1.0, 0.1*i, 0.1*i), alpha=1/3)
    # or
    plt.plot(data, c="red", alpha=1.0-0.1*i)
```

See also https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html

Comment: so I was showing a simple example, in reality I have about 50 different iterations, what I am trying to do is plot each iteration with a different shade of red. For example I=1 will have alpha=1/50, I=2 (alpha = 2/50)…...I=50(alpha=50/50).

Comment: Just a matter of scaling factor. Use ``plt.plt(data, c="red", alpha=(i+1)/iterations)``.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **c="red"** from the code it will work fine

```
    plt.plot(data,alpha=1/3)
```

[image: code]

Comment: Actually I want them all to be same color(red) but different shades